# How do you find the PDF when you are given the new variable wrp to a known random variable?

Tags: probability, derivatives, probability-distributions

My question is rather simple but here's a specific example I'd like to work with.

> The pareto distribution is given by the PDF $f(y:\theta)=\theta y^{-\theta-1}$ and $y_i$ are distributed with this PDF. Define $z=\text{log}(y)$ where the log is with base $e$ (i.e. ln). Find the PDF for $z$.

Well, I thought we can simply say $y_i=e^{z_i}$ so why not substitute that into our pareto PDF? Which I did;

> $$f(z;\theta)=\theta e^{-z(\theta+1)}$$

is what I got. Apparently, the answer is,

> $$f(z;\theta)=\theta e^{-z(\theta+1)} \times |\frac{dy}{dz}|$$

Where did the last term $|\frac{dy}{dz}|$ come from? Why is it an absolute value? Why is it multiplying it with what comes before it?

It boils down to the question "how did one derive this?"

Does anyone know?

Comment: Why not read the obvious: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Dependent_variables_and_change_of_variables

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep in mind that you are working with random variables so you can not simply substitute $y = e^{z}$ in the pdf for $Y$. The extra factor $\frac{dy}{dz}$ follows from the chain rule. I suggest you read section 2. in

http://math.arizona.edu/~jwatkins/f-transform.pdf